# Importing issues with Python Modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, scikit-learn

I was having issues getting the scikit-learn module to import into python. It would import into the python shell, but not when I did it through my IDE. After reading lots of things online, I got it to work by using:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
import sklearn
```

Does anyone have a suggestion so that I don't need to do the sys thing every time I want to use the module?

Comment: You are  almost certainly using a different interpreter in your IDE so it is looking for the module in a different path. What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE, find where you can change the "Python interpreter" setting, and point it to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`